if I connect a python program to mysql database and give the the program to someone else, can they access the database?
I have connected my python program to a database which uses mysql. I am running the mysql database from a server using 'localhost'. If I gave someone else my code, could they run it and access the database, or would there be an error since they may not have the database?
Heres my code:
import mysql.connector

AccountsDatabase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='test',
    port='3306',
    database='accountsdatabase')

Does this only connect to a local database called 'accountsdatabase' ?

It wouldn't just work on other people's local machine. They need to create a database manually or you can also add the script to create the database in your project

Okay thank you, would I use mysql to create the database in the project, or would I use something else, such as sqllite3?

If you want it to be portable and have modest requirements of the database, sqlite makes a lot more sense.

I agree with @deceze SQLite makes more sense for your usecase

Okay thanks, Ill try this. Edit: with sqllite, do I have to install anything else other than the python package if I only want the database connected to the program?

It depends on what your application does and how it is intended to be used. The idea of sending around an accountsdatabase fills me with dread. Are these standalone instances which are completely unrelated to each other? Or multiple people working on the same dataset?

Basically its an expense tracker, and I wanted a database which stores all the accoounts, account type and their recent contributions

Mysql server is a service so theoretically you could access it from any node on your local network if you set up the router and firewalls to allow it and replace 'localhost' with the internal IP address. There could be security issues to doing that though. You would normally only have one instance of the program accessing the database and other nodes connecting to the application but you don't have to.

what happens if I open the code myself, by cloning it from github on a device which is not on my local network - will I still be able to access the database?

It depends on how your network and mysql database is configured. Most likely you will not be able to access mysql outside from your local network. However, if you are asking such questions about database accessibility, then you probably should not be distributing applications using databases just yet. You could end up in a real mess! A piece of caution: while mysql database can be accessed over the network, it is unusual to develop 2-tiered applications nowadays, when the app connects directly to a database from a remote computer for security reasons.
